# Uninstall nouveau

Tags: 12.04, uninstall

How to completely remove nouveau to install the driver Nvidia? I tried to install the Nvidia driver as on ubuntu wiki but to no avail. All writes exactly what nouveau is. Tried to add to the blacklist and reboot and nothing too. Tried apt-remove command writes that it is not present.

Comment: OS Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: This may help: http://linuxers.org/howto/how-remove-nouveau-drivers-ubuntu

Answer (score 4):

`nouveau` is the accelerated graphics driver for nVidia graphics Cards.

`nouveau` can be removed and install NVidia by:

```
sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau && sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Download the driver (I assume you've done this) from nVidia's site. For sake of example I will call it `driver.run` for this.

You'll need to write down these instructions or access them via another device as you won't have a GUI soon.

1. Now open a tty1 session by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and log on with either your root account or your local account (which should have access to the `sudo` command).
2. Now type:

   ```
   sudo service lightdm stop
   sudo apt-get remove nouveau
   ```
3. Navigate to where you saved your `driver.run` file with

   ```
   cd /directory/where/you/saved/it
   ```
4. Then type

   ```
   chmod +x driver.run
   ./driver.run
   ```
5. Once that finishes (there's a prompt where you have to agree to licensing terms and other things) install `nvidia-settings` with:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings-###
   ```

   Where ### matches the version number you downloaded (331 in my case)
6. Now, reboot your computer with

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```

This should work for you. If it doesn't, you should be able to reinstall nouveau by again opening a tty1 session with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and run

```
sudo apt-get install nouveau
```

Comment: What pisses me off is that every time I upgrade my Linux, this driver automatically replaces by nVidia driver and it leaves the fan always running because the GPU is always on. So I always have to remember to uninstall it and reinstall the latest nVidia. You'd think the canonical folks would fix this

Answer (score 0):

Great answer, User224082. As a relative newbie, I lack the street cred to be able to vote, but this worked like a charmal, although I had to go to command line (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and then reboot to have it take effect. I had tried to install an upgrade to the Nvidia drivers with their own installer, but it wouldn't install because Nouveau was in use. Then Nouveau went and changed my display to 640x480 (just in spite, I'm sure). This did the trick. My Manjaro distro is hosed as well, and I'll modify it to use there as well.

Answer (score 0):

it is a great idea to purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau but at my system it still does system calls to nouveau. these are generating error messages on TTY until i reach the graphical display.

i recommend also: blacklisting the nouveau module from kernel via /etc/modprobe.d and updating the initramfs.